iPhone Mirroring not working (macOS Sequoia and iOS 18 Beta 2s)
I have the 2nd beta versions installed on my Mac & iPhone, with wifi and bluetooth enabled on both. When I open the iPhone Mirroring app, it asks for my password and then gets stuck on the connecting screen while my iPhone's screen is off, and when its not. I restarted both devices multiple times and even re-enabled SIP as well as changed the Mac security from full to reduced, both in the recovery menu.
Any other ideas for how to get it working?

Hi! Could you list the builds since soon the public betas will arrive and that’s the second public beta might be a fourth developer beta… letting people know what exact version has bugs also makes it more likely someone will chime in with the build where this works.

Sounds like a bug which you should report

I did report the bug now.
